# Basics of Collections.synchronizedMap in java

Tags: java

I have a class with huge static data structure. and many threads might be read-accessing it in parallel. I am suggested to use Collections.synchronizedMap

private static Map < String, HashSet < String >> HashSets =
    Collections.synchronizedMap (new HashMap < String,
                                 HashSet < String >> ());

As per http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ , I need to use synchronized() keyword while accessing values.I don't understand it quite well.

How should I modify below accesses:

```
if (HashSets.get (lang).contains (st))

if (HashSets.containsKey (lang) == false)

HashSets.put (lang, testhashset);
```

Any links explaining in detail should be useful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to protect all the little maps, then you need to lock the big map (or some other convenient globally-accessible object) *whenever* you manipulate them. Single method calls that just access the big map itself are fine, as it's synchronized. But that first call needs to be, i.e.,

```
synchronized(HashSets) {
    if (HashSets.get(lang).contains(st)) ...
}
```

You'll also need to lock the big map while you're iterating over the keys of any map, or you'll risk `ConcurrentModificationException`s.

As another poster has pointed out, this isn't a very good design. Even if you make it work, the performance will be poor, as the single large lock will greatly reduce concurrency. A `ConcurrentHashMap` holding little `ConcurrentHashMap`s would be a much better idea.

Answer (score 0):

What the spec page is trying to say is that you have to synchronize when you need multiple accesses to the returned map that depend on each other (iterating for example). But single independent are thread safe and atomic.

So in your case since you want to perform the put only when condition from the IF-operations apply, you should wrap the whole thing in `synchronized {}` like this:

```
synchronized(HashSets ){    
   if (HashSets.get (lang).contains (st))
      if (HashSets.containsKey (lang) == false)
         HashSets.put (lang, testhashset);
}
```

ps. You should not use variables starting with uppercase character as variable names (common convention). HashSets -> hashSets